# View declaration languages for JavaServer Faces

Tags: jsf, facelets

In the JavaServer Faces documentation it is written that it is possible to use different view declaration languages.

But, Facelets apart, it is impossible for me to find other view declaration languages to use with JavaServer Faces.

Where can I find other view declaration languages for JavaServer Faces?

Comment: See how Servlets were declared in your `web.xml` in JSF 1.*...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto servlets life cycle is completely different from Java Server Faces views life cycle.

Comment: Sorry, wanted to write **Facelets**, not **Servlet**...

Comment: Ignore Usagi's comment. It absolutely doesn't make sense in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just hasn't happened - view definition languag is an extension point in the specs, but no other VDL emerged (maybe it will?). The only actually used methods of building JSF views is the deprecated JSP way or the common Facelets way.

It looks like people are more interested in dynamically building component trees in code - but this area of JSF is also surprisingly tricky to get right (it's supposed to be improved in JSF 2.3).